# Progress Bar Before Div Loading

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

1. I need to show a progress bar or loading gif for 5 seconds before class .tiles is shown each time page loads

Need to show a simple "reload game" or "try again" button after function success inside class .tiles area instead of BootstrapDialog.show on whole page modal like in code below

Not have much knowledge of ajax

Comment: Can any one reply to help?

Answer (score 3):

first create a div with laoding gif, where you want to display it

```
<div id="loadingmessage" style="display:none;"><img src="URL"></div>
```

then use this before your ajax call

```
$('#loadingmessage').show();
```

then after success or failure function

```
$('#loadingmessage').hide();
```

same is the case with button, create a button and sets it to `display:none;` then after success function calls it to show. I hope it helps.

Comment: I have this    <div class="tile">  I want to show progress bar for 5 seconds before showing this div.... how to do it as ajax ode is for click fucntion

Comment: can i get any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pace](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) which requires minimal setup and will run automatically for every ajax request.

Pace is a light weighted library and you have the freedom to customize your loader.

Comment: How to use it? I do not know much ajax and even php can you do some fiddle for me...  ajax code which i had shown above is for click function as you can see above so i need to show this loader before class="tile"   show which has a small game in it

Comment: To use pace you just need to add the js and css to the page. Refer here [link]http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/pacejs-progress-bar/

Comment: Its says to use for page load, i need to load it only inside <div class="tiles">My game</div> for 5 seconds to load each time before showing game

Comment: Inside 'paceOptions' try adding this `target: '.tiles'`.

Comment: Do not know javascript much so please tell how to add this and make it to load before class =tile